# PHP - requiring bootstrap once for all files

Tags: php, composer-php

I have installed composer to autoload classes, and made a bootstrap file for the app, where I have this line:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Now, since I have 2 files in my app, for each I need to add this at the beginning of the file, in order to load the classes:

```
require 'app/bootstrap.php';
```

Is there a way of avoiding this, and having only one place, where I would pull all the classes for my files?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of avoiding this, and having only one place, where I would pull all the classes for my files?

There's `auto_prepend_file` configuration directive but you do NOT want to use it.  The common practice is to have one bootstrap file like you have and include it whenever neccessary.